# Resolve obfuscated IP addresses Node.js using the DNS module

Tags: node.js, npm, dns, bonjour, mdns

I know on a Mac OSX I can run this command: `dns-sd -q a5b3ef18-2e66-4e24-91d2-893b93bbc1c1.local` and it returns an IP address. Can I do this in Node.js? It seems like the `dns` module is mainly  used for `website -> IP`, not `IP -> IP (resolved)` conversions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Note: The imputted addresses will be mDNS, converted by Bonjour. I found the [Bonjour npm package/library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bonjour), but don't think it works in this case. Also, I found [mdns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdns) which has the [`mdns.dns_sd`](http://agnat.github.io/node_mdns/user_guide.html#dns_sd) function but I cannot seem to figure out how to use it in my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Node module that does exactly what you need.
[Multicast-DNS](https://github.com/mafintosh/multicast-dns) is capable of querying mDNS IPs to the standard IP format. The snippet on their README does what you need:

```js
var mdns = require('multicast-dns')()

mdns.on('response', function(response) {
  console.log('got a response packet:', response)
})

mdns.on('query', function(query) {
  console.log('got a query packet:', query)
})

// lets query for an A record for 'brunhilde.local'
mdns.query({
  questions:[{
    name: 'brunhilde.local',
    type: 'A'
  }]
})
```

Obviously you need to replace `brunhilde.local` with a valid mDNS ip. I simplified the code into this:

```js
function query(mdns_ip){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        mdns.on('response', function(response) {
            if(response.rcode === 'NOERROR'){
                resolve(response.answers[0].data)
                mdns.destroy()
            } else {
                reject(response.rcode)
                mdns.destroy()
            }
        })
        
        mdns.query({
          questions:[{
            name: mdns_ip,
            type: 'A'
          }]
        })
    })
}
```